# For which odd primes $p ≠ 5$ is 10 a qudratic residue modulo $p$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

For which odd primes $p ≠ 5$ is 10 a quadratic residue modulo $p$?

Saw a similar example using 5 and 15 and did my best to learn from those but still having a hard time grasping how to complete this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will this question help you? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586368/find-all-primes-p-such-that-14-is-a-quadratic-residue-modulo-p?rq=1

Comment: @AndréNicolas that's enough of an answer that it made me delete what I was in the middle of writing. You should post it as such.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: I will delete my comment. Answers are always preferable.

Answer (score 1):

$10$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$ if both $2$ and $5$ are quadratic residues or neither $2$ or $5$ are quadratic residue. By quadratic reciprocity, $2$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$ iff $p\equiv\pm  1\pmod{8}$ and $5$ is a quadratic residue iff $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{10}$. Now we may use the Chinese remainder thereom to state that $10$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$ iff $p\in \{1,3,9,13,27,31,37,39\}\pmod{40}$.